# How to retrieve list from POJO class

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to fetch the data from Firestore to Android. I am using the POJO (Java object class) method to get the values. How to proceed for this?

[image: 1]

Pojo class :

```
public class Documents {
    String documentID;
    String documentName;
    String documentDate;
    String inspectorName;
    String marketLocation;

public Documents() {

}

public Documents(String documentID, String documentName, String documentDate, String inspectorName, String marketLocation) {
    this.documentID = documentID;
    this.documentName = documentName;
    this.documentDate = documentDate;
    this.inspectorName = inspectorName;
    this.marketLocation = marketLocation;
}

public String getDocumentID() {
    return documentID;
}

public String getDocumentName() {
    return documentName;
}

public String getDocumentDate() {
    return documentDate;
}

public String getInspectorName() {
    return inspectorName;
}

public String getMarketLocation() {
    return marketLocation;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java :

```
List<Documents> documentsList = new ArrayList<>();

Documents documents = documentsList.get(); // Error to retrieve all data

primaryLayout(documents.getDocumentID(), documents.getDocumentName(), documents.getDocumentDate(), documents.getInspectorName(), documents.getMarketLocation());
```

Comment: `documentsList` is an `ArrayList` so calling `get()` without passing an index will not work. If you want to get the first object from the list you can use `documentsList.get(0);`.

Comment: Do paste your whole `MainActivity.java` file here. We would like to see what `primaryLayout()` method is doing?

Comment: i did it but it make an error

Comment: @ravi ok wait ya..

Comment: List<Documents> documentsList = new ArrayList<>();
After this you need to make rest call to fetch those entities.

Moreover documentsList.get() need an index to take out a document from list.

Comment: please dont post code in comments, edit your original question

Comment: error message : 
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

## i put the code in answer box

Comment: @Mr.Robot Did you solve your problem. Please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is a convention mistake as much as it is a blunder. You should name your POJO classes singular. That is, instead of naming it `Documents` you should have named it `Document` so that `List<Document>` is `documentsList` and `Document document = documentsList.get(<index>)` makes sense.

Line `Documents documents = documentsList.get();` is wrong since you are trying to get one `Document` from the `documentsList` by calling `get()` method but you are not passing an index value to the `get()` method. Also the `documentsList` variable is initialized just above this line which means, the list is most probably empty.

What I suggest you do is:

1. First off Refactor> Rename your POJO class from `Documents` to `Document`.
2. Second, after initializing the list of documents, add the instances of Document to the list by calling: `documentsList.add(new Document("documentID","documentName","documentDate","inspectorName","marketLocation"));` as many times as you have the `Document`s from your firebase by using an iterator like `foreach()`

Comment: add 'new' keyword - new Document

Answer (score 0):

you have only initialized the ArrayList ....Not it's objects....You have to initialize each of it's object and then you can access it by calling documentList.get(position)..
However this will not solve your problem of getting data from Firebase FireStore..
You can follow this link [adding fireStore to android](https://proandroiddev.com/cloud-firestore-android-is-easy-c940cb82715c)

Comment: thanks for your answer. By the way, i just want to get document id from pojo class, not all data..

Answer (score 0):

More code from MainActivity class

MainActivity.java :

```
    List<Documents> documentsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Documents documents = documentsList.get(); // Error to retrieve all data

    primaryLayout(documents.getDocumentID(), documents.getDocumentName(), documents.getDocumentDate(), documents.getInspectorName(), documents.getMarketLocation());

public void primaryLayout(String documentID, String documentName, String documentDate, String inspectorName, String marketLocation) {
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressLoader);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Documents documents = new Documents(documentID, documentName, documentDate, inspectorName, marketLocation);

    collectionReference.document(documents.getDocumentID()).collection("Products").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                itemsList.clear();

                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Items items = documentSnapshot.toObject(Items.class);
                    itemsList.add(items);

                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```